# Cannot get the Regex correct for Javascript to include special characters in a string replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following code:

```
$('.pure').on('keyup', function (e) {            
    e.preventDefault();
    var str = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s,.-^%]+$/ig, ''));
});
```

I want to only allow for the following characters:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 , . - % and space.
```

My string that I am entering in the input box:

```
You have selected the following date - %date%.
```

Results:

The % keeps being removed from the string. Other special characters are also being removed $& etc. Which is correct. But I do not want the % to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `-` to the end of the regular expression character class so it is not interpreted as a range.

```js
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s,.%-]/ig, '')
```